# Automate with watir on-screen keypad login

Tags: watir

I'm wondering how to automate with watir the clicks on a on-screen keypad. I'm trying to automate the login on this web, but I don't know how to recognize the numbers and click on them:
https://bancaelectronica.evobanco.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the HTML of the keyboard, each key is simply a link:

```
<div class="virtual_keyboard active">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">3</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">7</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">1</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">0</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">4</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">5</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">6</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">2</a></li>
    <li><a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">8</a></li>
    <li class="correction">
      <a id="btCorrect" href="javascript:void(0);" data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn delete-key">Corregir</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-target=".activeInput" class="keypad-btn value-key" href="javascript:void(0);">9</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="keypad-close">Cerrar</a>
</div>
```

You simply need to:

1. Activate the keyboard by clicking on the password field
2. Clicking the key links by text (since they are randomly sorted)

An example of typing a password of "123":

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto('https://bancaelectronica.evobanco.com/')

# Activate the keyboard
browser.text_field(id: 'cFDMTuKLOsuyeXQ').click

# Wait until the keyboard appears
virtual_keyboard = browser.div(class: 'virtual_keyboard')
virtual_keyboard.wait_until_present

# Enter the password by clicking the number links
virtual_keyboard.link(text: '1').click
virtual_keyboard.link(text: '2').click
virtual_keyboard.link(text: '3').click
```

The same approach can be taken for other on-screen keyboards. However, the exact elements to interact with will depend on the page's implementation of the keyboard.